# When Click to login Providing error

Tags: php

in this if in my database all the user details are held and i want to login then this code can generate error... my main work is to when i have data in databse then i can login with exist data it provide error and not logged and if filled wrong data then page not providing error, it redirect ..
ineed that when i fill correct then go to successfull page if filled wrong then provide error

```
<?php
include('./includes/config.php');     

if(isset($_POST['submit_form']))
    {
        $email1=$_POST["email"];
        $password1=$_POST["password"];
        $query="select * from login";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num>0)
            {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $email2=$_POST["email"];
                    $password2=$_POST["password"];
                }
                if ($email1==$email2 && $password1==$password2) {
                    echo "You are in";
                }
                else {
                    echo "Sorry $email. Incorrect password!";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing check on login condition because you are comparing to every user. Also use mysqli_ instead of mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_form']))
    {
        $email1=$_POST["email"];
        $password1=$_POST["password"];
        $query="select * from login where email='$email1' AND password='$password1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num>0)
        {
                    echo "You are in";

        }
        else 
        {
                    echo "Sorry $email. Incorrect password!";
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the entered username and password against every user in the database. So for every other user, you print the error message. And even when you find the matching user, you don't stop, you keep going.

You should just look for the user with the username and password that was entered:

```
$email1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = "select * from login where email = '$email1' and password = '$password1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num == 0) {
    echo "Incorrect email or password.";
} else {
    echo "You are in";
}
```